# Remote NX login to Ubuntu, Gnome can't mount CD/DVD drive

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, mount, nx-server

Even though I'm sitting next to it, I log into my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system via [NX Free Edition](http://www.nomachine.com) from another system at the moment (this is temporary, not worth buying a KVM for). Curiously, though, when I do that Gnome's auto-mounting fails for CD/DVD media (I haven't tried other kinds) with a "Not Authorized" error. (When I put the media in the machine's own DVD drive, not the one on my client box.) For instance, when I put the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS installation CD in, I get this error:

```
Unable to mount Ubuntu 10.04 LTS amd64 - Not Authorized
```

This does **not** happen if I log into it locally (not via NX) with the same user account.

When using NX, I **can** mount the media if I go to `mount` directly:

```
tjc@midnight:~$ sudo mkdir /media/dvd
tjc@midnight:~$ sudo mount -r -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/dvd
tjc@midnight:~$ ls /media/dvd
autorun.inf  casper  dists  install  isolinux  md5sum.txt  pics  pool  preseed   README.diskdefines  ubuntu  wubi.exe
```

...which, along with the "not authorized" error, suggests some kind of permissions problem to me (doh). What I find odd is that the same user is involved in both cases (local and via NX).

I'm new to Ubuntu on the desktop (used it and other distros on servers for years), so I'm afraid I don't know how this auto-mounting is happening. I *think* it's handled by the `gvfs` package and its daemon, but that's about as far as I got (and perhaps I've taken a left turn even getting that far).

Although I can work around it with `mount`, does anyone know how I might get auto-mounting to work?

**Update** The `nx` user used by NX doesn't seem to be the issue. I wouldn't have *expected* it to be, since I'm logging in as myself, but I'm on unfamiliar ground. The only processes running as `nx` are:

```
nx        4484  4416  0 09:24 ?        00:00:00 sshd: nx@notty   
nx        4568     1  0 09:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/NX/bin/nxssh -nxservermode -l tjc localhost -p 22 -x -2 -i /usr/NX/etc/keys/node.localhost.id_dsa -o PubkeyAuthentication yes -o RSAAuthentication yes -o RhostsAuthentication no -o PasswordAuthentication no -o RhostsRSAAuthentication no -o StrictHostKeyChecking no /usr/NX/bin/nxnode
nx        4664     1  0 09:24 ?        00:00:00 nxserver -c /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --login
```

...where all the Gnome stuff is either running as me (`tjc`) or `gdm`. But just in case, I added `nx` to the `cdrom` group via `usermod`. When that didn't work, not being sure which services might want restarting, I just did the Windows thing and rebooted the machine entirely. No change. In fact, I temporarily added the `nx` user to *all* groups that `tjc` was a member of (except the `tjc` group), but that didn't do it either, so I think the `nx` user isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with consolekit and policikit. Read this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/221363

There is a workaround for FreeNX-Server. The problem is I am using Neatx-Server...

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly from my forays into NX, it runs under a separate user account - double check that the `nx` account (or whichever it is, might have to list all user accounts to find it) has proper permissions to mount the drive (add to group `cdrom` ?)

Comment: Thanks, but no luck (`usermod -a -G cdrom nx`, then check in `/etc/groups` that it's been added, and not seeing a difference immediately and not being certain which services may need restarting, I did the Windows thing and rebooted the machine). There is an `nx` user, but all of the Gnome stuff (including `gvfsd`) says it's running under either `gdm` or `tjc` (my login). The only processes running under `nx` are the SSH login and `nxserver`. I'll update the question.

Comment: (I tried all other groups `tjc` was a member of, too, just to be sure.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Is `tjc` a member of `cdrom`? I just realized that you were using `sudo` to mount it from the command line. Locally I think Ubuntu uses the `pmount` system, which might bypass said security, but also might not be set up for however nx id starting up gdm.

Comment: `tjc` is a member of `cdrom`, yes; but without the `sudo`, `tjc` can't manually mount the drive: `mount -r -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /home/tj/dvd` results in "mount: only root can do that". I don't think Ubuntu 10.04 uses `pmount` (at least, I can't find anything with `pmount` anywhere in the name on my filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me installing FreeNX new version, with this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX